# HDRI backgrounds are different brightness and i can't figure out why!

Tags: hdri

So i have a scene i'm happy with using an HDRI from blenbderkit. But strangely enough if i open up the same HDRI on a new file, its a lot brighter and does not look right. I've checked all nodes & render / viewport settings between the 2 files and everything looks to be the same! Please see examples below.
Can anyone advise how i can get a new project to look the same ? instead of this super bright HDRI
New Project Example:
[image: Brand new project HDRI]

My Old Project:
[image: Previous Prject]

Any Help greatly Appreciated!

Comment: Please use screenshots instead of photos of the screen, especially when comparing color, photos are more difficult to work with.  You've also cut off the Outliner, which hopefully would show any non-HDRI lighting used.  A screenshot of your World shader would be helpful.  Is this Cycles or EEVEE?  And it can be a good idea to post your blend file, or a truncated version of it that has the problem, and the HDRI packed (if feasible, if not a link to which Blenderkit HDRI you're using). The Blender StackExchange has its own service to share blend files: blend-exchange.com/help

Comment: If it's the same HDRI, and the same render engine, then you can adjust its _Strength_ setting in the World Properties panel of the Properties editor.  If both projects use the same version of blender, that shouldn't be necessary; but the units for _Strength_ have changed from time to time.

Comment: Often, blender uses "Linear" as the default color space for Environment (HDRI) Textures - however, some HDRI images are built to work in sRGB color space - try changing it. If that doesn't work, try changing the _View Transform_ from "Filmic" to "Standard" under _Render Properties > Color Management_.

Answer (score 1):

These examples use the included HDRI sunset.exr in Blender 3.1.2.  Although you said “I've checked all nodes & render / viewport settings between the 2 files and everything looks to be the same” there are a few things that could've been missed.  One is if in both your files your World Shader has the HDRI in an Image Texture Node:

[image]

Or (as should be for an HDRI) an Environment Texture Node:

[image]

The above examples were rendered in Cycles, are both of yours?  Or is one in EEVEE:

[image]

And (thanks to Marty Fouts comment above) are you sure the Background node's Strength is the same in each file?

[image]

Comment: I will re post when i get home showing the Nodes, Both images are Cycles GPU rendering and both HDRI's are at strength 1